# how to install Haxe on centos 7

Tags: centos, installation, haxe

how to install Haxe on centos 7

from this [tutorial](https://haxe.org/download/linux/),
there are no Centos platform  ,are there any body install on Centos successful?

Comment: Didi you try some of variant from tutorial . Post some error log if you have it ....

Answer (score 1):

Should be similar to the Fedora instructions although those seem to use `dnf` which doesn't look like it's available out the box on CentOS.

At the very least it looks like its installable via rpm http://rpms.famillecollet.com/rpmphp/zoom.php?rpm=haxe